# Как убрать все небуквенные символы из каждой ячейки столбца и поместить результат в новый столбец?

Tags: python, pandas, pymorphy2

Есть [датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Vv_qryIV448lCKlNyeD4VniFB06oe7L/view?usp=sharing). В нем нужно текст из ячеек столбца `body` очистить от небуквенных символов и заглавные буквы заменить на строчные и добавить в исходный фрейм столбец, в котором каждая ячейка будет результатом обработки ячейки столбца `body` соответствующей строки.

Код:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer

df = pd.read_csv('Example.csv', encoding = 'utf-16')

#Удалим из текста разрывы строк \r\n, приведя содержимое столбца с типу строки
df['tokenize'] = df['body'].str.replace('\r\n','')
df.tokenize.head()

m = MorphAnalyzer()

# убираем все небуквенные символы
regex = re.compile("[А-Яа-яA-z]+")

def words_only(text, regex=regex):
    try:
        return regex.findall(row.lower())
    except:
        return []

print(*words_only(df.tokenize[0]))
```

выводит нужный результат для содержимого первой ячейки столбца `body`, а именно:

> сегодня и завтра подключайтесь к бесплатной онлайн конференции welcome
> to gamedev которую при инфоподдержке организует google
> совместно с игровыми студиями кефир belka games nexters десять
> специалистов из разных направлений разработка геймдизайн арт аналитика
> и маркетинг расскажут как попасть в геймдев с чего начинать и почему
> делать игры здорово подключайтесь если хотите работать в игровой
> индустрии начало в по московскому времени https vk cc bysuvu

А как создать новый столбец фрейма данных и в нем проделать такую операцию для содержимого столбца `body` каждой строки?

```
for row in df.tokenize:
    df['words_only'] = words_only(df.tokenize(row))
```

дает ошибку.

Comment: @MaxU Я обрезал датасет для образца. Видимо, не получилось. После Вашего замечания выложил исходный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df["body_norm"] = (df["body"]
                   .str.replace("\r\n", " ")
                   .str.lower()
                   .str.replace(r"[^a-zа-я\s]", ""))
```

результат:

```
In [347]: df["body_norm"]
Out[347]:
0      сегодня и завтра подключайтесь к бесплатной он...
1      привет на этой неделе познакомимся с профессие...
2      хотели бы получить степень магистра но дистанц...
3      календарь на телефоне не врет уже  февраля а в...
4      юлия ушла с должности руководителя отдела в ту...
                             ...
995    дизайнбитва сегодня голосуем какой логотип луч...
996    сегодня на свой первый проект я даже смотреть ...
997    макрос для word  это не просто программа котор...
998    в сегодняшней статье подробно расскажем как сд...
999    расписание вебинаров на эту неделю  как всегда...
Name: body_norm, Length: 1000, dtype: object
```